# Add sort by votes to new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, sorting, new-nav

M.I.A - sorting by votes, one of the more useful features the old design have.

> [image]

Can it please be added in the new navigation design as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's still there, in the [popular tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=popular&show=alltime&sort=votes).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: So "new" tab shouldn't have sort by votes?

Comment: new questions have low votes. How would you expect it to behave?

Comment: Good point, thanks! :)

Comment: @Sklivvz This sorts the *popular* questions by votes, but doesn't sort *all* questions by votes.  How do we find the highest and lowest voted questions over the entire site in this new nav design?

Comment: @AdamDavis you are mistaken: this shows all the questions by votes (which is a sort that privileges the most popular).

Comment: @Sklivvz I see that I needed to select "all time" as well.  However, I don't see any questions voted below a 0. How do we view these questions using the new navigation system?

Comment: @AdamDavis at the moment we're hiding them. If you have a good reason for showing them, please open a feature-request explaining why that would be a good thing and we'll consider it

Comment: @Sklivvz That might be reasonable on main sites, but certainly it's wrong to hide feature requests and discussions on meta sites just because they are unpopular.

Comment: I'll consider adding an answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259352/new-navigation-sort-and-view-negative-votes later

Comment: I'd like to suggest that this is a bad location for it. I just spent 5 minutes trying to figure out how to do this. At the very least, shouldn't it be easier to find this?