# New navigation: sort and view negative votes

Tags: support, sorting, new-nav

When I use the new navigation to sort by votes, I noticed that if I go to the last page, negative vote questions no longer appear and the lowest vote count is 0.

1. Is there a reason for this?
2. Is there a way to see negative vote questions with the new navigation?

Here's the approach I'm using to sort by votes:

- [Add sort by votes to new navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256823/add-sort-by-votes-to-new-navigation)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason for this?

Probably so people wouldn't get embarrassed and have their heavily downvoted, downvoted again. It can be very annoying when users know that their worst questions are allowed to be viewed by everyone. People don't want that, and allowing negative vote questions will cause a revolt. I have bad questions myself and I don't want to share them with the rest of the world. So no thank you.

> Is there a way to see negative vote questions with the new navigation?

You can see negative vote questions when viewing the `newest` tab because these are the new questions that need to be viewed, answered, and whatever is needed to do with those questions. No matter what `filter:`, `sort:`, or `show:` is, you can see negative vote questions.

You *might* see it in the `need answer` tab, but negative vote questions are rarely unanswered and most of time, already answered the second/minute it was posted.

You can only see it in the `popular` tab if you downvote a 0 score question then click the logo. Then you will see the question which is now a negative vote question. But don't do that is not necessary...